# The layer was not drawn completely - ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, feature-service

I am publishing a hosted feature service layer onto ArcGIS Online organization from ArcMap. The service has just one layer that is stored on a file gdb on my PC. I am able to publish a service with no problem; I am also changing the Max Record Count property (in the Service Editor wizard) to support drawing larger number of features in an ArcGIS Online map viewer.

The feature layer has about 70,000 features. All of them are uploaded fine into a hosted feature layer. I am able to query the feature service from the Services Directory and getting all of them back.

However, when trying to view the very same feature layer in a map viewer, I am getting the notoriously famous error message:

`Layer did not draw completely`

`LayerName did not draw completely because there are too many features to display in this area of the map. Try zooming in or setting the visibility range for the layer.`

The solution for this would be to adapt the max number of records that can be returned as described in [the Esri KB](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43461). However, I already have 80,000 for this limit set.

It's a bit difficult to judge (my features are tiny polygons and I am in a small scale), but it seems as there are more than 1,000 features drawn in a map viewer, so the problem is not related to the default max records parameter. A rough estimate would be that I get a 4th part of them drawn, something about 15-20K.

**Is there any hard limit on the number of features from a hosted feature layer that can be drawn in a map viewer?**

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried this again since the last two updates to AGO from a browser that supports WebGL?

Comment: Hi Simon, I don't any longer use AGOL so there is no point in testing :)

Comment: Author no longer has the issue